# teams chat component in dynamics, is the component available

Tags: chat, microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

[dynamics chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo53d.png)

> is this component available i.e(Gifs, emoji , edit the text ) rather building the chat component using fluent ui northstar

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Teams chat component is the part of Teams product, so I think it's not available as reusable component for 3rd party apps development.

You can raise a user voice here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new